# How to get vectors of memory cell & the last output of $LSTM$ in keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

In [this](https://techblog.rtbhouse.com/files/user2vec-user-modeling-using-lstm.pdf) research paper the following paragraph appears,

> The state of every LSTM model is stored in **two fixed-size
>   vectors of real numbers called the memory cells and the last
>   output.** Since our LSTM model is trained to predict user’s
>   behavior, elements of these vectors are the natural candidates for the user-dependent features. They can be extended
>   by the resulting predictions (answers to the questions). This
>   way 218 new features are obtained from the memory cells
>   (100) and the last output (100) of the second LSTM layer
>   and from the final output (18).

I am aware of getting weights of each layer. But how to get these two vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answering after reading [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/) article. Actually, the paragraph is saying that $218$ new features are obtained from -

1. **Memory cells or Memory units of 2nd LSTM layer**: It will give a vector of $100$ cell states (cell state corresponding to each memory cell). Note that the dimension of the vector is equal to the number of hidden memory cells.
2. **Last output of 2nd  LSTM layer**: It will give a list of $100$ cell outputs (cell output of each memory cell/unit).
3. **Final output**: Final output would eventually comprise of an $18$ dimensional vector. Dimensions are - $2$ for (a), $6$ for (b), $4$ for (c), $3$ for (d), $2$ for (e), $1$ for (f).

From the same article, it can be achieved in keras using `return_state=True` parameter.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import LSTM
from numpy import array
# define model
inputs1 = Input(shape=(3, 1))
lstm1, state_h, state_c = LSTM(2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)(inputs1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=[lstm1, state_h, state_c])
# define input data
data = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).reshape((1,3,1))
# make and show prediction
print(model.predict(data))
```

This ouputs,

```
[array([[[-0.00559822, -0.0127107 ],
    [-0.01547669, -0.03272599],
    [-0.02800457, -0.0555565 ]]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.02800457, -0.0555565 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.06466588, -0.12567174]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Just to add to above answer, return sequences = True  gives the output from each cell. And if make that argument as FALSE , you will get output from last cell.